# Open Mac Office 365 Excel File in Windows - 'we found a problem with some content'

Tags: excel, windows, macos, office365

[image]

Excel files (xlsx, xlsm, xltx) created and updated by MS Excel in MacOS. When it's opened with MS Excel in Windows, error encountered as the print screen above.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

1. Upload the file to OneDrive in Mac
2. Open the file from [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com) on the web browser (it would be opened in MS Excel Online)
3. Do some changes and Save the file
4. Sync and open the file from OneDrive in Windows

After that, the file should be OK without issue.

```
*For my case, I'm using Office365 for both Mac and Windows
```